# How do I calculate the closest element in another list for all of my list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of "vertexes" (x,y,z positions):

```
vert_list_1 = [[1.2, 3.4, 5.6]...[-5.2,-6.0,2.9]]
vert_list_2 = [[10.0, 9.1, 2.7]...[117.0, 1.1, 2.8]]
```

The lists have different lengths.

I wish to find a list closest_vert_2_index such that

```
np.linalg.norm(vert_list_2[closest_vert_2_index[i]] - vert_list_1[i])
```

is minimised.

closest_vert_2_index can contain duplicates (thankfully, otherwise it's a much much harder problem!)

Naively I would do

```
closest_vert_2_index = []

for vert in vert_list_1:
   best_dist = None
   best_vert_2_id = None

   for i, vert_2 in enumerate(vert_2_list):
      dist = np.linalg.norm(vert_2 - vert)
      if best_dist is None or dist < best_dist:
         best_dist = dist
         best_vert_2_id = i

   closest_vert_2_index.append(best_vert_2_id)
```

But I'm wondering if anyone can think of anything faster.

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to work with `list`s, since even your naïve approach wouldn't work (`vert_2 - vert` will fail as `-` is not defined on lists).

Comment: @divakar The associated question is related, but there is an extra loop that is not being taken care of by the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @norok2 I don't see a loop there. And `Kdtree` one should be good enough.

Comment: @Divakar look at the OP code in both question, the other one has one loop, this one two loops. The inputs are also different. It may be that kdtree is useful, but the two questions are not asking the same problem.

Comment: @norok2 For duplicates, I think we look at the answers. The accepted one there with ckDtree solves it there pretty efficiently and likewise here without any changes, assuming array inputs (which I think is safe as the posted code seems to assume the same). These are two essentially asking the same question, just different words.

Comment: I have an answer for this which I'm unclear is appropriate for the other but may be - I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

Convert your lists into numpy arrays and you can do it this way. This is quite fast:

```
import numpy as np

vert_list_1 = np.array(vert_list_1)
vert_list_2 = np.array(vert_list_2)
closest_vert_2_index = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(vert_list_2[:,None] - vert_list_1, axis=-1)
```

Get the difference of every pairwise row, find its norm and get the index of minimum for each row.

Another way is to use KDTree and query:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

vert_list_1 = np.array(vert_list_1)
vert_list_2 = np.array(vert_list_2)
tree = cKDTree(vert_list_2)
dist, closest_vert_2_index = tree.query(vert_list_1, k=1)
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks - but unfortunately my lists are 200k ish long, and this approach requires a 200kx200kx3 allocation, which is a memory problem.

Comment: @omroth perhaps you should build a NumPy array instead of a `list` to begin with?

Comment: @Omroth in that case you should use KDTree. I updated the post. The question is closed. Please kindly accept the answer so others find it helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

As you are calculating distance between two "vertexes"* and expects duplicates to appear, consider using [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator. To use it you need to write function - in your case it would be something like `calculate_dist(vertex1, vertex2)`. After you decorate it using `lru_cache`, result will be not only returned but also stored, so during next call with same parameters it will be retrieved from storage rather than calculated.

*calculating distance can be done via so-called *pure* function, i.e. output depend solely on input. `functools.lru_cache` is designed to be used with pure functions.